# linker command failed Error while initializing UIViewController in Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am new to IOS and I have two UIViewControllers. Both created using code (no nib files or story board). I am trying to instantiate second View controller from my first one and I get linker command failed error. This is how I am calling my view controller. The error occurs on the first line of code.

```
ViewControllerTest *v = [[ViewControllerTest alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:v animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here's the detailed error I get:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewControllerTest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You need to update your question with details about the linker error.

Comment: Could you post what the actual error is?

Comment: updated my post with detailed error.

Comment: Did you import the `ViewControllerTest.h`?

Comment: luk2302: Yes, I did.

Comment: You probably never setup ViewControllerTest.m to be included in your target.

Comment: @rmaddy: It's included in the target. I just verified.

Comment: Then look at the ViewControllerTest.m `@implementation` line. Is the class name really `ViewControllerTest` and not something else by mistake?

Comment: the class name is correct.

Comment: Then the .m file isn't really a member of the target you are building.

Comment: clean & build just in case...

Comment: I tried that. also tried option + clean and didn't work.

Comment: @rmaddy : You were correct. My file was in incorrect Target.

Answer (score 0):

You should present v

```
[self presentViewController:v animated:YES completion:nil];
```

EDIT: Do you make your ViewController inherit from UIViewController? It must be in its header file.

```
 @interface TestViewController : UIViewController

 @end
```

Comment: oops. Thanks. That was my mistake. Even if I comment that line out, I get the same error.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly how my ViewControllerTest looks.